# Spring sleuth bagage fields are not correctly set to MDC context

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, slf4j, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Spring Sleuth version 3.1.9 along with Spring Webflux but when trying to get the MDC context of the bagagefields inside the logging it fails before I used a await from coroutines. But when I use `BaggageField.getAllValues()` it does have all the values on both places and the traceId and spanId is filled in by both places in the MDC context (which are also at both places the same). Here is some code:

```
fun routes(
    handleRequest: HandleRequest,
    userHandler: UserHandler
) = coRouter {
    "api/v1".nest {
        POST("/users/find", userHandler::findUser)
    }
    
    filter(::addMDCContext)
    filter(handleRequest::requestHandler)
}

suspend fun addMDCContext(request: ServerRequest, next: suspend (ServerRequest) -> ServerResponse): ServerResponse {
    val callerField = BaggageField.create(CALLER_ID_MDC_PARAM)
    callerField.updateValue(request.headers().firstHeader(CALLER_ID_HEADER_NAME) ?: "[not set]")

    val callerVersionField = BaggageField.create(CALLER_VERSION_MDC_PARAM)
    callerVersionField.updateValue(request.headers().firstHeader(CALLER_VERSION_HEADER_NAME) ?: "[not set]")

    val userAgentField = BaggageField.create(USER_AGENT_MDC_PARAM)
    userAgentField.updateValue(request.headers().firstHeader(USER_AGENT_HEADER_NAME) ?: "[not set]")

    val resourceField = BaggageField.create(RESOURCE_MDC_PARAM)
    resourceField.updateValue("${request.methodName()} ${request.uri()}")

    val requestIdField = BaggageField.create(REQUEST_ID_MDC_PARAM)
    requestIdField.updateValue(request.headers().firstHeader(REQUEST_ID_HEADER_NAME) ?: UUID.randomUUID().toString())

    return next(request)
}

private const val CALLER_ID_HEADER_NAME = "x-caller-id"
private const val CALLER_VERSION_HEADER_NAME = "x-caller-version"
private const val USER_AGENT_HEADER_NAME = "User-Agent"
private const val REQUEST_ID_HEADER_NAME = "x-request-id"

private const val CALLER_ID_MDC_PARAM = "caller"
private const val CALLER_VERSION_MDC_PARAM = "caller_version"
private const val USER_AGENT_MDC_PARAM = "user_agent"
private const val RESOURCE_MDC_PARAM = "resource"
private const val REQUEST_ID_MDC_PARAM = "request_id"

class HandleRequest(
    private val tracer: Tracer
) {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}
    
    suspend fun requestHandler(request: ServerRequest, next: suspend (ServerRequest) -> ServerResponse): ServerResponse {
        val startTime = ZonedDateTime.now()

        return try {
            withContext(tracer.asContextElement()) {
                next(request).let { serverResponse ->
                    val endTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
                    logger.infoWithMdc(
                        "duration" to "${Duration.between(startTime, endTime).toMillis()}",
                        "status_code" to serverResponse.rawStatusCode().toString(),
                    ) { "Successful response" }
                    serverResponse
                }
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

class UserHandler {
    private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {}

    suspend fun findUser(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        logger.info { "TestA - thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name} - ${BaggageField.getAllValues().size}" }
        val requestBody = request.awaitBody<TrainsNearUserLocationsRequestBody>()
        logger.info { "TestB - thread: ${Thread.currentThread().name} - ${BaggageField.getAllValues().size}" }

        val foundUser = getUser(request)

        return ServerResponse.ok()
            .bodyValueAndAwait(
                ApiSuccessResponse(
                    payload = foundUser
                )
            )
    }
    
    ...
}
```

With the following condig in the application yml:

```
sleuth:
    baggage:
        correlation-fields:
            - caller
            - caller_version
            - user_agent
            - resource
            - request_id
        local-fields:
            - caller
            - caller_version
            - user_agent
            - resource
            - request_id
    trace-id128: true
    reactor:
        instrumentation-type: decorate_on_each
    async:
        enabled: true
```

By findUser this are the logging statements: `TestA - thread: parallel-2 - 4` and `TestB - thread: reactor-http-nio-5 - 4` which shows that it switches threads but do have on both alle the bagagefields. So was wondering why at the TestA logging statement the bagagefields are not in the logging of slf4j but by TestB they are as expected.